# Invalid JSON string because of an additional quote

Tags: python, json

I'm attempting to load this JSON string but it is invalid because of the additional quote with in the name of the item. `"name": "1/2\" Drive 2" Extension"`. How can I id and correct for the additional quote?

```
              {
                  "@context": "http://schema.org",
                  "@type": "Product",
                  "name": "1/2\" Drive 2" Extension",
                  "image": "https://snap-on-products-hr.imgix.net/SX2.jpg",
                  "description": "Buy 1/2\" Drive 2" Extension, Item #SX2, from Snap-on Store.",
                  "brand": "Snap-on",
                  "sku": "SX2",
                  "offers": {
                    "@type": "Offer",
                    "url": "https://shop.snapon.com/product/Knurled-Extensions/1-2%22-Drive-2%22-Extension/SX2",
                    "priceCurrency": "USD",
                    "price": "26.25"
                  }
              }
```

Below is how I'm attempting to load it via python. `content` string is a place holder for the example.

```
import json

content = '{"@context": "http://schema.org", "@type": "Product", "name": "1/2\" Drive 2" Extension", "image": "https://snap-on-products-hr.imgix.net/SX2.jpg", "description": "Buy 1/2\" Drive 2" Extension, Item #SX2, from Snap-on Store.", "brand": "Snap-on", "sku": "SX2", "offers": { "@type": "Offer","url": "https://shop.snapon.com/product/Knurled-Extensions/1-2%22-Drive-2%22-Extension/SX2","priceCurrency": "USD","price": "26.25"}}'

dictTool = json.loads("".join(content))
```

Comment: The best option by far is to fix whatever the broken source of that JSON is.

Comment: you need to escape that additional quote with a backslash, without that you json data is completely invalid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Unfortunately I'm unable to. The string is retrieved from a site.

Comment: Problem worth dropping them a note about how to produce correct JSON. :-)

Comment: I think best case scenario would be if you can get the source fixed, assuming that's not an option, I would've tried to remove `name` key and value from the input using string handling, and then load the json. This way I'll get the rest of the data, and for name, I would remove all the quotes up until the comma and then add it to dictTool. Also, this will only work if `name` is the only inconsistency in the json. If there are more then I'd have to repeat for them as well.